# Visual C++ MessageBox

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Using visual c++ can't get the message box to compile.

this one works. `MessageBox::Show("hello the world");`

Obviously i can't hardcode all my messages so i want something like this :

```
string s = "hello the world";
MessageBox::Show(s); | also tried MessageBox::Show(NULL,s);
```

doesn't work. also tried :

```
char* test = (char*)s.c_str();
MessageBox::Show(test);
```

include  on top of my file

searched google, no code sample on msdn for c++ messagebox, most of stuff i found isnt for visual c++.

thanks

Comment: try `L"hello world"`. Also what do you use: .NET or MFC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using managed code in the C++/CLI language.  Which requires using the System::String type for strings:

```
String^ s = "hello the world";
MessageBox::Show(s);
```

Do make sure you actually want to write this kind of code.  It is not standard C++.  If you do then make sure you read a C++/CLI book or tutorial to learn the language.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
        } catch (Exception ^ex) {
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
        }
```

Perhaps your strings are the wrong format? Trying initializing with

```
_T"My String"
```

or

```
L"My String"
```

has worked for me before. You may be defaulting to 8-bit ASCII or some other encoding for your declarations which get cast to some other type by the object being initialized which cannot then be interpreted (or cast) by `MessageBox::Show()`